# How to send Facebook notifications to all users of a specific region from web application using graph api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a web application. My application will send Facebook notifications to all the users of a specific region. How this can be done?

Comment: check out my answer. side note: you should improve your question to the stackoverflow standard. include what you have tried so far, the code you have tried, the research you have done, where exactly you got stuck, ...

Answer (score 0):

The only useful way to do this is to have a database with all your App users, with a field for the region/location. After that, just select all users for a specific region and use the notifications endpoint.

More information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/services/appnotifications